# Restore mouse wheel zoom functionality after a ".on("wheel.zoom", null)"

Tags: d3.js

so I have an if statement in my zoom function, one that detects if the Ctrl key (or Meta key) is being pressed down in order to use the mouse wheel to zoom.

If Ctrl/Meta key is NOT pressed, only use pan.
If Ctrl/Meta key is pressed, use pan and zoom.

I'm very close to the solution but I have a problem below. Relevant pieces of code below:

```
var zoomListener = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 3, 1])
    .on("zoom", zoom);

var svg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoomListener);

var group = svg.append("g");

var zoomKey = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    zoomKey = true;
    console.log(zoomKey);
  }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    zoomKey = false;
    console.log(zoomKey);
});

function zoom() {
  if (zoomKey) {
    // svg.on("wheel.zoom");
    group.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  } else {
    svg.on("wheel.zoom", null);
    group.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }
}
```

So my question is, I have:

```
svg.on("wheel.zoom", null);
```

How do I reset or put this back as default? Is there an svg.off? I tried to find specific documentation on the second argument for the event listeners, but couldn't find it.

Also tried things like:

```
svg.on("wheel.zoom", true);
```

Thanks to anyone who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [zoom.filter()](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#zoom_filter).
Reads like this in the end:

```js
var zoomListener = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 3, 1])
    .on("zoom", zoom)
    .filter(function() {
        // Exclude wheel event unless zoomKey is set
        return zoomKey || !(d3.event.type === "wheel");
    });

// no changes here  

function zoom() {
    // No condition needed in here anymore
    group.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```